# How to force EclipseLink's @PrivateOwned to perform delete before insert

Tags: java, eclipselink, updates, unique-constraint, ownership

I have an entity which has `@OneToMany` private ownership of a collection of another entities.

That other entity has some unique constraints over different set of columns.

The problem arises when I want to update the main entity (together with changed child entities).
EclipseLink does insert before delete, so sometimes, an insertion violates the constraint and throws an exception.

Is there a way to force the deletion of child entities before inserting their updated counterparts?

Answer (score 3):

I know, I'm a bit late, but anyway:

```
 UnitOfWork uow = JpaHelper.getEntityManager(em).getUnitOfWork();
 uow.setShouldPerformDeletesFirst(true);
 uow.setShouldOrderUpdates(true);
```

But sometimes also updateBeforeInsert would be needed, no idea to force that.