# problem with Eclipselink removing and adding elements to a collection

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an entity `Medico` with a collection`<MedicoMatricula>`, the problem happens when I try to remove a `MedicoMatricula` and add another (very similar), the SQL executes 1st the INSERT and not the DELETE so the unique restriction is triggered. All this is done by a merge(Medico) with CASCADE.ALL of the collection after User/Client confirmation, so I can't divide the process of deleting the 1st item as soon as the user did it (do a merge) and do another merge with the new item.

Is it a way to change this Eclipselink behavior? tell it to 1st run the deletes before the inserts or updates??

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(name = "medicomatricula_medico_provincia", columnNames = {"medico_id", "provincia_id"})
    ,
    @UniqueConstraint(name = "medicomatricula_provincia_matricula_tipo", columnNames = {"numero", "provincia_id", "tipo"})
})
public class MedicoMatricula implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Medicos medico;
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Provincia provincia;
    /**
     * Única por médico y provincia, sin importar las especialidades
     */
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer numero;
    /**
     * M= Médico, O= Odontólogo, P= Psiquiatra, K= Kinesio, N= Nutricionist
     */
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 1)
    private String tipo;
```

Comment: Try UnitOfWork uow = (UnitOfWork)( (JpaEntityManager)em.getDelegate() 
).getActiveSession( em ); 
uow.shouldPerformDeletesFirst(); On the EntityManager you are calling merge on. This will force EclipseLink to order the delete statements first, before updates or inserts.

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20467896/496099